# tokenmismatchexception on uploading a large file laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I get a token mismatch error when I try uploading a large file in laravel 5. I am using the token field in my form.

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

I already tried few methods:

1. increasing upload_max_filesize and post_max_size.
2. changing php.ini file and restarting apache services.
3. disabling the csrf middleware for that route, but the file is not fetched in this case !

Here is my view:

```
<form id="csvform22345" role="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('admin/QC/uploadtomaindbcsv') }}">
  {!! Form::token() !!}
  {{--<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">--}}
   <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="{{ $pid }}">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
                                            <input id="csvfile2" type="file" name="file2" required class="file-loading">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="alert alert-info small mar-top">Only .csv files allowed.</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Controller function:

```
    public function upload_to_maindb()
{
    try
    {
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2G');
    ini_set('post_max_size', '4G');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '5000000');
    ini_set('max_input_time', '5000000');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '200M');
    //echo "try block" ; die;
    $now = new DateTime();

    $timestamp = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $pid = Input::get('pid');
    $file = Input::file('file2');
        $project = Projects::select('project_type')->where('project_id',$pid)->get()->first();
        $pt = $project->project_type;
    if($file !='') {
        $pid = Input::get('pid');
        $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
        //echo "its here";
        //die;
        $datas = array();
        unset($datas);

        while (($row = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE) {
            $contact['company_name'] = $row[0];
            $contact['website'] = $row[1];
            $contact['contact_name'] = $row[2];
            $contact['first_name'] = $row[3];
            $contact['last_name'] = $row[4];
            $contact['email'] = $row[5];
            $contact['title'] = $row[6];
            $contact['address'] = $row[7];
            $contact['city'] = $row[8];
            $contact['state'] = $row[9];
            $contact['zip_code'] = $row[10];
            $contact['country'] = $row[11];
            $contact['phone_number'] = $row[12];
            $contact['fax_number'] = $row[13];
            $contact['industry'] = $row[14];
            $contact['sub_industry'] = $row[15];
            $contact['revenue'] = $row[16];
            $contact['employees'] = $row[17];
            $contact['data_category'] = $pt;
            /*
            $contact['sic_code'] = $row[18];
            $contact['naics_code'] = $row[19];
            $contact['linkedin_source'] = $row[20];
            */
            $contact['last_updated_via_project_id'] = $pid;
            $datas[] = $contact;
        }
        foreach (array_chunk($datas, 200) as $data) {
            Master_datarecords::insertIgnore($data);
        }
    }
    unset($datas);
    //echo "done"; die;
        $msg= "successfully inserted";
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            $msg = "some error occured, please check the file.";
        }

    $approved_projects= array();
    $pids= array();
    $i=0;
    $projstat = ProjectuserHelpers::GetProjectStatusId("approved");
    $projects_object=Projects::where('project_status',$projstat)->get();
    if(!($projects_object->isEmpty())) {
        $projects = $projects_object->toArray();
        foreach ($projects as $val) {
            $approved_projects[$i]['pid'] = $val['project_id'];
            $approved_projects[$i]['projectname'] = $val['project_name'];
            $approved_projects[$i]['record_count'] = Transitional_records::where('fk_project_id', $val['project_id'])->count();
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return View::make('admin/home_page/QC/QCtomaindb',compact('approved_projects','msg'));
}
```

I couldn't find anything besides these in the internet. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Let me know the file size and provide your view and controller code to

Comment: there you go @MayankPandey

Comment: Can you show your session configurations?

Comment: Why -- hyphens are there in {{--<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">--}}

Comment: See Piya, token mismatch error arises when you are posting a form and token value is missing.

Comment: I already used the form token , the input for token is commented because i tried both methods. N no it is not the token error for token being misplaced cause the same works for smaller size files.  @mayank

Comment: Ok Piya. Check this: http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-l40-csrf-tokenmismatchexception-when-uploading-large-files

Comment: I am not using sessions. Would you still require it ?@VaheGalstyan

Comment: Piya you have to change the settings in php.ini to pst a big size file and restart the server. It will resolve the problem

Comment: No. I tried that. Not working. Server error.

Comment: "This site can’t be reached" @MayankPandey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124630/discussion-between-mayank-pandey-and-piya-desai).

Answer (score 2):

I thing it happens due to `post_max_size` limit .

I increased it by `50M` and also increased upload max file size .

Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You into file php.ini. 
Find this :

> max_execution_time and max_input_time.

Edit

> max_input_time = 1440 and max_execution_time = 1440.

I tried and succeeded